# External USB Harddrive not recognized

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, hard-drive, data-recovery

I got an external HardDrive that I want to recover. I don't know what the previous user did, but it was definitely a software change.

lsusb recognizes a harddrive with the following output:

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge
```

it also appears to under ’/dev/' as '/sdb'

```
sda
sda1
sda2
sda5
sdb
```

however ’lsblk’, ’fdisk’, ’gparted’ and ’testdisk’ don't recognize it.

mounting doesn't work either

the output of the 'dmesg' is:

```
[ 1249.258540] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[ 1249.413276] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa
[ 1249.413285] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 1249.413291] usb 2-1.2: Product: USB 3.0 Device
[ 1249.413295] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Intenso
[ 1249.413299] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 31100000000000004D5F
[ 1249.413970] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1249.414806] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: Quirks match for vid 174c pid 55aa: 400000
[ 1249.414875] scsi host8: usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[ 1250.415968] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Intenso  USB 3.0 Device   0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 1250.416802] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 1271.738369] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[ 1272.742477] ......not responding...
[ 1405.812177] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1405.812192] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Not Ready [current]
[ 1405.812198] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[ 1427.164687] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1427.164704] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Not Ready [current]
[ 1427.164712] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[ 1434.282050] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[ 1441.399599] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[ 1441.399613] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1476.986620] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[ 1477.989228] ......not responding...
[ 1611.060363] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1611.060381] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Not Ready [current]
[ 1611.060388] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[ 1632.412920] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1632.412936] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Not Ready [current]
[ 1632.412942] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[ 1646.647701] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

Comment: Define "don't recognize it"

Comment: Based on the errors in your `dmesg`, it appears to be a hardware problem.  Either the drive is dead, or possibly the sata cable has been unplugged.

Comment: @psusi: I hoped that the delivered description would define it sufficiently. But if there is more, pleaes do indicate what else I could tell you. So I will send it in and see what Intenso has to say to it (or possibly just plug the SATA cable back in) thanks anyway